# Bug: show 1 more comment

Tags: discussion, bug

I notice in this question here [Java - How to get items out of a list with String Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992060/java-how-to-get-items-out-of-a-list-with-string-arrays) that there are no comments when I clic in the link, when I click in the link it disappear, but when I refresh the page, the link shown again.

[image]

I think it is a **bug**

Comment: Deleted my original comment as now I read it more, this is a known issue caused by a race condition that isn't worth fixing.  Pointed to a better duplicate which explains this in the comments